# Fit JavaFX WebView Browser content to window

Tags: java, webview, javafx

How can I fit the JavaFX WebView content to window size?

I would like to display browser content scaled to parent windows size. `SetScale` does the trick partially because component acts crazy and scaled browser is positioned in the center of parent window. The size of displayed sites is always 1280x800 and window size can be set manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is based on this: https://gist.github.com/RupprechJo/7455537

The solution is to put WebView into zooming pane and there perform content resize.

It may look kind of slovenly but shows the main idea and... works!

```
package webscale;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class WebScale extends JApplet {
    static ZoomingPane zoomingPane;
    private static JFXPanel fxContainer;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JavaFX 2 in Swing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JApplet applet = new WebScale();
                applet.init();

                frame.setContentPane(applet.getContentPane());

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                applet.start();

                frame.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
                        if (zoomingPane != null) {
                            zoomingPane.setZoomFactors((double)(frame.getWidth()/ 1280.0), (double)(frame.getHeight() / 800.0));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        fxContainer = new JFXPanel();
        fxContainer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        add(fxContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // create JavaFX scene
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createScene();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createScene() {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        zoomingPane = new ZoomingPane(webView);
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setCenter(zoomingPane);
        fxContainer.setScene(new Scene(bp));
        webView.getEngine().load("http://google.pl");
    }

    private class ZoomingPane extends Pane {
        Node content;
        private final DoubleProperty zoomFactor = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1);
        private double zoomFactory = 1.0;

        private ZoomingPane(Node content) {
            this.content = content;
            getChildren().add(content);
            final Scale scale = new Scale(1, 1);
            content.getTransforms().add(scale);

            zoomFactor.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                    scale.setX(newValue.doubleValue());
                    scale.setY(zoomFactory);
                    requestLayout();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            Pos pos = Pos.TOP_LEFT;
            double width = getWidth();
            double height = getHeight();
            double top = getInsets().getTop();
            double right = getInsets().getRight();
            double left = getInsets().getLeft();
            double bottom = getInsets().getBottom();
            double contentWidth = (width - left - right)/zoomFactor.get();
            double contentHeight = (height - top - bottom)/zoomFactory;
            layoutInArea(content, left, top,
                    contentWidth, contentHeight,
                    0, null,
                    pos.getHpos(),
                    pos.getVpos());
        }

        public final Double getZoomFactor() {
            return zoomFactor.get();
        }
        public final void setZoomFactor(Double zoomFactor) {
            this.zoomFactor.set(zoomFactor);
        }
        public final void setZoomFactors(Double zoomFactorx, Double Zoomfactory) {
            this.zoomFactory = Zoomfactory;
            this.zoomFactor.set(zoomFactorx);
        }

        public final DoubleProperty zoomFactorProperty() {
            return zoomFactor;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 'Stack Pane' to organise your layout. Then use 'Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds(); ' to get the users window dimensions.

```
package com.ruemerc;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainWindow extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        WebView webview = new WebView();
        StackPane stackPane=new StackPane();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(webview);

        WebEngine webEngine= webview.getEngine();
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       
        webEngine.load("http://www.ruemerc.co.ke/apps/smsgateway");
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                  new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                  public void changed(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {                               

                         if(newState.toString().equals("FAILED")){                       

                         webEngine.loadContent("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Page Title</title></head><body>"
                                + "<h1>Error:</h1>"
                                + "<p>Internet connection Problem.</p>" +"<button onclick=\"window.location.href='http://www.ruemerc.co.ke/apps/smsgateway/'\">Retry</button>"

                                + "</body></html>");
                         }

                  }


              });

        Scene scene=new Scene(stackPane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Ruemerc SMS");
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("images/logoedtrack.png"));

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

        //set Stage boundaries to visible bounds of the main screen
        primaryStage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
        primaryStage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
        primaryStage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());

        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```