# Display part of a dynacim web in webview

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I can display a `web page` via `webview` like this :

```
        URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
                    WebView webComponent = new WebView();

                    webComponent.getEngine().load(url.toString());

                    borderPane.setCenter(webComponent);
                    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,450,450);
                    myFXPanel.setScene(scene);
                });
```

Ex it displays `stackoverflow.com` page, But I wanna display just a part of that, ex the painted part in this [image: pic].

How is it possible?

Edit : I can not display it via `loadContent` method, because it has lots of `scripts` the have been addressed and the device is back of a `busybox`, so i can not find the address of them, so my question is how can I display just a part of a `webpage` in my `webview`?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this that I know of. Your best bet is either going to be somehow resizing the window to only show that part OR checking out the HTML, seeing what that specific part needs to look and function the way it does and then delete all the other HTML.

Comment: If I choose the easy way and want to resize in that part of the page.
How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796742/fit-javafx-webview-browser-content-to-window